# How to access hidden themes in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, themes

How do you access the hidden international themes in Windows 7?  for say Switzerland or Great Britain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the other international themes copy and paste the following path into the search box and hit Enter.

> C:\Windows\Globalization\MCT

In the MCT folder you will find additional themes for Canada, Australia, South Africa, and Great Britain.

[image]

Copy/paste the wallpapers or the theme files. Enjoy!

**Source:**

> http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/3476/access-international-themes-in-windows-7/

Comment: If you search for *.theme or *.jpg while in that folder, you can get all the themes or wallpapers respectively in one folder view, for easy access. And rather than copying and pasting the theme files, you can double click on them to install them.